# Why create new functions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I'm going through the JavaScript road trip on Code School, which I've found very useful and seems to make learning JavaScript really stick and make more sense for me. I've tried several books before this without much luck.

Anyway, on to the question; consider the following

```
var fruits = ["Apple", "Orange", "Pineapple", "Cranbery", "Pomegranate" ];
var fruitJuice = fruits.map(function (fruit) {return "\n" + fruit + " juice";});
alert(fruitJuice);
```

Why create a new variable called 'fruit' for the map function. I've been playing around in jsfiddle and I could use the original 'fruits' array without changing it's contents.

So for example:

```
var fruits = ["Apple", "Orange", "Pineapple", "Cranbery", "Pomegranate" ];
var fruitJuice = fruits.map(function (fruits) {return "\n" + fruits + " juice";});
alert(fruitJuice);
```

also works fine but uses the same fruits variable at the start.

Is this best practice or am I missing something important here?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: make sure you understand what `map` is. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: What is the problem you're dealing with. Otherwise question is to broad..

Comment: `fruits` inside the function is NOT the same as the original `fruits`. It's a new variable in a new scope, that just happens to have the same name as the original `fruits`.

Comment: Thanks @basilikum that is the kind of answer I was looking for / half expecting. Makes more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var fruitJuice = fruits.map(function (fruit) {return "\n" + fruit + " juice";});
```

This is a callback, a concept you're apparently unfamiliar with. What `map` does is essentially this (simplified explanation):

```
var result = [];
for (var i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
    result.push(callback(fruits[i]));
}
return result;
```

`map` takes each item in the `fruits` array, passes it into the supplied `callback` function and takes whatever that function returns. So your callback function is:

```
function (fruit) {return "\n" + fruit + " juice";}
```

`fruit` here is a parameter for the function, i.e. `fruits[i]`. You need to name the parameter somehow if you want to refer to it. Of course you still have access to any other variable in scope inside the function, but `fruit` is the unique array element passed to it by `map`.

Comment: Thanks, yes I'm very much still learning...

This all makes sense, but why does it still work if I use the same variable fruits rather than fruit in the callback?

Comment: If you name the function parameter `fruits` its name is `fruits`. Not related to any other variable `fruits`.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a new variable fruit instantiates the variable inside the function itself.
Let's say you are calling a name by alerting hello + name.
You could do it like this:

```
var Name = 'bob';
alert('hello ' + Name);
```

But we could also do it like this, which gives it also the possibility to use it later in the code with other names.

```
function sayHello(Name) { alert("Hello " + Name); }

var Name = 'Bob';
var Name2 = 'John';

sayHello(Name);
sayHello(Name2);
sayHello('Jack');
```

This should return 3 alerts, one with Hello Bob, and the others with Hello John and Hello Jack.
With your function you're doing the same thing, using the value of a variable inside a function but without calling it inside the function.

With the .map function it takes all of the values out of the array and places it inside your function. So I could also do something like this.

```
var Names = ['Bob', 'John', 'Jack'];

Names.map(sayHello(Names));
```

This prints the names in almost same way, using name as callback variable inside the function. So this prints: Hello Bob, John, Jack.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer.
Your .maps example doesn't appear to be working.

Comment: I just fixed it, now it is working (Mostly spelling mistakes, sorry)

Answer (score 0):

the map2 method(as original map method) creates a new array and (as deceze says) needs a parameter.
If you look at the console you will discover how this method works

```
   Array.prototype.map2=function(callback){
        var result=[]
        console.log(this)
        console.log(callback)
        console.log(callback(this[0]))
        result.push(callback(this[0]))
        for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
            result.push(callback(this[i]));
        } 
        return result 
   }
  var arr=["Apple", "Orange", "Pineapple", "Cranbery" ]
  console.log(arr.map2(function(a){return "a " + a + " juice"}))
  /*console.log(["Apple", "Orange", "Pineapple", "Cranbery" ].map2(function(b){return 'big'+b}))*/
```